# C# Visual Studio Microsoft 2022 BindingNavigator not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bindingnavigator

I am trying a project Database Connection from Guru99 tutorial for C#. I have to put a BindingNavigator in Windows Forms App but I don't have that in my ToolBox.

Comment: Hi, does the answer can help you or you have any update about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for Visual Studio 2022 but Visual Studio 2019 does not have a BindingSource available in the toolbox for one reason or another so with that see if the following provides a BindingNavigator in your toolbox.

If this is the case, try adding the following class to your project.

```
public class CoreBindingNavigator : BindingNavigator
{
    public CoreBindingNavigator()
    {
        AddStandardItems();
    }
}
```

Build the project and you should see the CoreBindingNavigator in your toolbox.

Comment: This worked for me. It had to be in the same project as the form I was designing, though. It didn't work when I added it to my 'Common' project. Thanks!

Comment: I never tried the component in a class project and used it in a forms project but just did and zero issues.

Comment: Wherever you put this, it seems to work and thank you for the answer. If just exposing the old class to .Net Core like this works, then I don't understand why it is not included in Core out of the box. I wonder if we will run into any issues...