# Binding Navigator Visual Studio 2022 .NET 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, bindingnavigator

Binding Navigator control do not apear in toolbox on VisualStudio 2022, i try to add control manualy adding the dll, but do not work, is the control deprecated?

Comment: What project template and what settings have you used?

Comment: C# Windows Forms Aplication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Visual Studio Microsoft 2022 BindingNavigator not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341212/c-sharp-visual-studio-microsoft-2022-bindingnavigator-not-showing)

Comment: thank you now the control is visible but when i add to a form all butons are disabled

Comment: Well, you need to connect it to a BindingSource and connect the BindingSource to a DataSource that has data.